# Cuando subo APK a la Google Play Store en pruebas internas, solo me coge el Target SDK Version no el Min SDK Version

Tags: unity3d, unity

Despues de subir la APK/ABB a la tienda de google me coge solo la version 31 de SDK:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando en el archivo Manifest de tengo el minimo a 19 y el Maximo a 31:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto solo me es compatible con 10 tipos de telefonos.

Adjunto todos los datos del analisis de la Aplicacion en la prueba interna que esto haciendo antes de lanzarla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se porque me pasa esto, llevo 2 semanas enganchado y no consigo darle solucion. Al principio me da 17000 y pico dispositivos compatibles y al cabo de un rato me lo restringe solo a 10. No entiendo si el "minsdkversion" es igual a 19.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que generar 2 archivos el Abb y el symbols.zip y subirlos los 2.

Cuando se hace el build hay que marcar las 2 opciones:

- Build APP Bundle y Create Symbols.zip.
  -Quitar el developent build.
  -Descomprimir el symbols.zip.
  -Subir 1º el Abb. 2º El .zip 3º El TXT

Ya te cogera todos los SDK.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/326356)